# deal with very long url address in java

Tags: java, http, parsing, url

I use httpConnection in java to load and parse JSON file from URL address.
The URL length is more then 10K chars but the maximum I can use through HTTP connection is 2K chars.
How can I deal with it?

Comment: According to RFC7230 an URL should not be longer than about 8k characters. AFAIK Apache commons Http client supports (k but not 10K. If you need 10K it is a bad design of the server (use POST instead of GET).

Comment: so what can I do in I have REST API url with more then 10K chars?

Comment: Read the documentation carefully, usually such large requests are sent not in the URL (GET request) but as POST request.